# React FixedDataTable cell always get everything is undefined

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

i'm trying using React FixedDataTable, and i always get everything is undefined.
i still new to this library, could anyone help me figure out what's wrong.

here's my form :

```
import React from 'react';
const {Table, Column, Cell} = require('fixed-data-table');

class MyCell extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var {rowIndex, data, field, ...props} = this.props;
    return (
      <Cell {...props}>
        {data[rowIndex][field]}
      </Cell>
    );
  }
}

export default class PeriodTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const {periodTableHeader, periodTableField, periodData} = this.props;

    console.log(periodData);
    console.log(periodTableHeader);
    console.log(periodTableField);

    return (

      <div>
          <Table
            rowsCount={100}
            rowHeight={50}
            headerHeight={50}
            width={1000}
            height={500}>
            {periodTableHeader.map((data, index) => {
              let header = periodTableHeader[index]
              let field = periodTableField[index];
              return(
                <Column
                  header={<Cell>{header}</Cell>}
                  cell={<MyCell data={periodData} field={field} />}
                  width={200}
                />
              )
            })}
          </Table>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

> console.log(periodData):

[image]

> console.log(periodTableHeader):

[image]

> console.log(periodTableField):

[image]

is my syntax is wrong maybe?

Answer (score 0):

First your `periodData` should be an array of objects. From your `console.log(periodData)` i see that its just an object. Make sure you send an array of objects.

Second `rowsCount` that you pass to `Table` should be `periodData.length`

That should do load the data in your table.

```
 <Table
        rowsCount={periodData.length}
        rowHeight={50}
        headerHeight={50}
        width={1000}
        height={500}>
```

// ...